# Exception during Generating Java source from WSDL url

Tags: maven-2, wsdl, pom.xml

I am trying to generate java file from wsdlurl. some of them are working fine but some have problem in that. 
here is the code.

```
    <plugins>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.12</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>ad1</id>
                            <goals>
                                 <goal>wsimport</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <wsdlUrls>   
                                    <wsdlUrl>https://adcenterapi.microsoft.com/Api/Advertiser/v7/Reporting/ReportingService.svc?wsdl</wsdlUrl>
                                    <wsdlUrl>https://adcenterapi.microsoft.com/Api/Advertiser/v7/Administration/AdministrationService.svc?wsdl</wsdlUrl>
                                    <wsdlUrl>https://adcenterapi.microsoft.com/Api/Advertiser/v6/NotificationManagement/NotificationManagement.asmx?wsdl</wsdlUrl>
                                    <wsdlUrl>https://adcenterapi.microsoft.com/Api/Advertiser/v7/CampaignManagement/CampaignManagementService.svc?wsdl</wsdlUrl>
                                    <wsdlUrl>https://sharedservices.adcenterapi.microsoft.com/Api/Billing/v7/CustomerBillingService.svc?wsdl</wsdlUrl>
                                    <wsdlUrl>https://sharedservices.adcenterapi.microsoft.com/Api/CustomerManagement/v7/CustomerManagementService.svc?wsdl</wsdlUrl>
                                </wsdlUrls>
                                <target>2.1</target>
                                <xjcArgs>
                                    <xjcArg>-XautoNameResolution</xjcArg>
                                </xjcArgs>
                                <bindingDirectory>src/jaxws/wsdl/adCenter</bindingDirectory>
                                <keep>true</keep>
                                <packageName>com.microsoft.AdCenter.soap</packageName>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
</plugins>
```

I have did these before also but i don't have any issues. Am very much confused this time.

Can you guys try to generate Java source code using wsdl in a pom file. Since i have tried in my system am getting exceptions as

```
[ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
  line 1 of https://adcenterapi.microsoft.com/Api/Advertiser/v7/CampaignManagement/CampaignManagementService.svc?xsd=xsd1

[ERROR] (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.
  line 1 of https://adcenterapi.microsoft.com/Api/Advertiser/v7/CampaignManagement/CampaignManagementService.svc?xsd=xsd1

[ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
  line 1 of https://adcenterapi.microsoft.com/Api/Advertiser/v7/CampaignManagement/CampaignManagementService.svc?xsd=xsd1

[ERROR] (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.
  line 1 of https://adcenterapi.microsoft.com/Api/Advertiser/v7/CampaignManagement/CampaignManagementService.svc?xsd=xsd1

[ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
  line 1 of https://adcenterapi.microsoft.com/Api/Advertiser/v7/CampaignManagement/CampaignManagementService.svc?xsd=xsd1

[ERROR] (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.
  line 1 of https://adcenterapi.microsoft.com/Api/Advertiser/v7/CampaignManagement/CampaignManagementService.svc?xsd=xsd1

[ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
  line 1 of https://adcenterapi.microsoft.com/Api/Advertiser/v7/CampaignManagement/CampaignManagementService.svc?xsd=xsd1

[ERROR] (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.
  line 1 of https://adcenterapi.microsoft.com/Api/Advertiser/v7/CampaignManagement/CampaignManagementService.svc?xsd=xsd1
```

Any Ideas ?

thanks

Comment: I am getting the same error using just one WSDL file.  This wsdl file is quite complex.  Have you found a resolution to your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just guessing, but it appears that there are naming collisions.  You might try breaking your wsimport into multiple steps and using different `<packageName>` sections for each.

Comment: The two WSDL that are causing your problems are CustomerManagementService and CampaignManagementService, its the name spaces of the xsd imports that are causing conflicts.